# fieldQuery(String, String) is undefined

Tags: java, elasticsearch

i am new to elk,
I have an simple code of elasticsearch in Java like this :

```
 Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
                .put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();

            TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build(); 

            client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("1.2.3.4", 9200)));

        SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("logstash-log*").setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
                .setQuery(fieldQuery("host", "2.3.4.5"))
                .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();

            SearchHit[] results = response.getHits().getHits();
            for (SearchHit hit : results) {
              System.out.println(hit.getId());    //prints out the id of the document
              Map<String,Object> result = hit.getSource();   //the retrieved document
            }
        System.out.println("test");
```

So, can you give me suggestion, I've looking for the solution
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `termQuery("host", "2.3.4.5")` instead.

`fieldQuery()` was an old query available in ES 0.90, which has been deprecated and removed.

Comment: still cannot use termQuery because i got the error msg "The method termQuery(String, String) is undefined"

Comment: You need to add `import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.termQuery;`

Comment: Have you been able to try this out?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "get all field value"?

Comment: Any chance with this?

Comment: hi Val, return results is get  _id  field, but how can i get all field that host is 1.2.3.4

Comment: This question was about `fieldQuery` vs `termQuery ` and you said it worked after adding the `import` statement. If you have a different issue now, you should ask a new question so that we don't cram too much into this thread.

Comment: hi Val,the issuse have crated  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384276/how-to-using-regexp-in-elasticsearch  , can you give me suggestion, I've looking for the solution Thanks...

Comment: None of the three answers satisfy you?