# how to using regexp in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, regex, elasticsearch

i have a lot of field name in elcsearch ,
for example :

> web_logfield_A, web_logfield_B ,web_logfield_C::abc,
>   
> apach_logfield_A, apach_logfield_A

if i want to get these fields value (
web_logfield_A, web_logfield_B ,web_logfield_C::abc )

can i using Regex expression for  "field name"   to query like

```
/web_logfield[A-Za-a_]+/
```

i have try to using .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("",""),
but it's looks like cannot do that ?
which method in JAVA API can do that ?

Comment: i think you should use `web_logfield[^,]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with a `query_string` query like this

```
.setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("xyz").field("web_logfield_*"))
```

where `xyz` is what you're trying to match in those fields

Comment: are you mean xyz is field name ?

Comment: No, "xyz" is what you are searching in all the fields whose name matches `"web_logfield_\*"`

Comment: got error , Exception in thread "main" Failed to execute phase [dfs], all shards failed; shardFailures

Comment: Try without the backslash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112658/discussion-between-stefansaye-and-val).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the specific format, you can use this:

```
web_logfield[^,]+
```

or even

```
web_logfield_[^,]+
```

That is: get everything after `web_logfield` up to a comma.

See it in action: https://regex101.com/r/dT4nJ2/1

To process the results, then you can [create an array of the regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6020436/1983854).

Answer (score 0):

In regex,"+" means that there is one character  to match,so your regex can not match "web_logfield_C::abc",I think you can use "web_logfield_[A-Za-Z]+*",which can match one or more characters before "+"

Comment: which method in JAVA API can do that ?

Comment: For examples on doing regular expressions using Java, please look at this [Java - Regular Expressions tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for helping out members of the community. Your answer provides for some understanding of regular expressions and this is useful - however, since the question specifically wanted to know the Java API/method please consider updating your answer to address this aspect of the question. Also look at some tips on [how to make your answers great](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use **Pattern** to write regex and use **Matcher** to match the string.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("web_logfield[A-Za-a_]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find()){
   String res = m.group();
   System.out.println(res);
}
```